# mule 4 reading csv file skips first line

Tags: dataweave, mule4

In Mule 4 I am reading a large csv file doing a transform and needs to write the contents to a db table. The csv file has no headers. When I run the integration by default the first line is skipped as if the default is predetermined as a header.

```
        <sftp:listener doc:name="On New or Updated File" doc:id="f36f06d1-9dd1-4ea6-80fc-016a1b0fb2ac" config-ref="SFTP_Config" directory="${inbounddirectory}" recursive="false">
            <scheduling-strategy >
                <fixed-frequency frequency="120000" startDelay="1" />
            </scheduling-strategy>
            <sftp:matcher filenamePattern="xyz*.csv" />
        </sftp:listener>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="e36120be-559b-4c32-b241-74752b340f45" message="FILENAME #[attributes.fileName]"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="2b6cbad1-6484-4eed-9b26-cf01354c5690" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload map ((payload , indexOfPayload) -> {
data1:payload[0],
data2:payload[1],
data3:payload[2],
data4:payload[3],
data5:payload[4],
data6:payload[5]
})]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="239df117-9eb5-43b3-b913-469217b759dd" message="PAYLOAD #[payload]"/>
```

I took a look at the application-types.xml under resources and looks like the header is set to false as below

```
<types:property name="headerLineNumber" value="0"/>
<types:property name="header" value="false"/>
<types:property name="isQuotedString" value="false"/>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sFTP listener properties, go to the MIME Type tab, select "application/csv" from the dropdown list and add the "header" parameter with the value "false":

[image]

Comment: Haven't seen documentation about this. Also seen this question a few times here. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: please find the documentation link in the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't look into application-types.xml. That file is autogenerated and not supposed to be read by humans.

What you need to do is to ensure to set the right [reader properties](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats-csv#xml-configuration) for the CSV file at the source component for that payload. In this flow that is the `<sftp:listener>` source. You will need to add an `outputMimeType` attribute
to set the header input property to false, because the default is true.

```
<sftp:listener ... outputMimeType="application/csv; header=false">
```